# SEO: Changing product name and domain name to be found when searching for the old name

Tags: seo, google-search, redirects

When switching to a new product name (and also new domain), it seems to make sense to place 301 redirects from all old pages to the new domains pages.

But: what if almost everyone searches for the old name in e.g. Google Search. Will the new domain and new product name ranked as it currently is when searching for the old name? This will be important.

Or, from an SEO perspective, might it be better to not set 301 redirects and just setup a small landing page on the old domain informing about the name change and with a huge link to the new domain?

Please, does someone have practical experience with this issue? Lots of information can be found on how to keep the old SEO score/..., but not on how it influences the search results of the old name. Or, if anything can be done to improve it.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When switching to a new product name (and also new domain), it seems to make sense to place 301 redirects from all old pages to the new domains pages.

Yes. That makes a lot of sense for both SEO and usability.

> Will the new domain and new product name ranked as it currently is
> when searching for the old name?

If the new domain does not mention the old product name, most likely not.

The only exception is if the product name is hyper-specific and very little content exists on other websites.

**Landing page for the old name**

I would implement 301 redirects where it makes sense and then set up one landing page mentioning the old product and the name change on either the old or the new domain. If feasible, I would put this landing page on the old domain and move it to the new domain after a few months. That would carry the lowest risk and highest likelihood of ranking for the old term.

**Alternative approach**

Would it be possible to mention the old name on the new websites everywhere? Like a small paragraph on each landing page? Maybe even have it in the title of the landing pages, "*Product XY (formerly ABC)*"? Then you could just 301 redirect everything.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Malte! It worked out wonderfully this way. (Combined landing page for the old one and mentioning the old name on the new site)